# Sorting data in a table

Tags: r

I want to create a new  excel output that I will use as an appendix for my paper and I want to create three columns and sort the table alphabetically by a column "namn". 
I have been applying a following code:

```
tabell<-count(data, "namn")
print(tabell)
print(tabell$namn)
tabell$proportion<-tabell$freq/sum(tabell$freq)
print(tabell$czestosc)
tabell2=data.frame(tabell$namn, tabell$freq, tabell$proportion)
# I have been attempting with ”=” as well as with ”<- ”

tabell2[order(tabell2$namn)]
tabell2[order(tabell2$namn, )]
tabell2[order(tabell2$namn, ), ]
tabell2[order(namn ) ]
tabell2[order(namn , )]
tabell2[order(namn, ), ]
#and all combinations of the last 6 commands with assignment to a    variable.
```

Nevertheless, it does not work.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Can you try `tabell2[order(tabell2[, "namn"]),]`

Comment: It does not yield any error, it yields an output with a header and 3 rows. Is that correct? I mean, can I rely on it and assume that it has executed the sorting command over the entire column?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
newdf <- order(tabell2$ctr)
```

You don't need to index the data as per your examples, instead you can just create a new data frame based on the newly sorted values.

Comment: When applying:     newdf<-order(tabell2$namn). It yields: "Error in order(tabell2$namn) : argument 1 is not a vector".                                            (In the previous code I posted there was a wrong column name, I have corrected it, now it reffers to a correct column name).

Comment: I re-read your question and noted that you had alphabetical data, but when I tried a repeatable example using the letters data -  "order(letters)" it still works.

Comment: It would help if you can post an example of "tabell2$namn"

Comment: I cannot publish it, as these are patients' data. To supplement the information delivered, it is a character variable.